# What is important for Pharmaceutical companies to answer with Big Data Analysis?

Tags: dataset, bigdata, apache-spark, bioinformatics

I am a data scientist, and I have some biological background (genetics). I have been asked to give a talk for our customers from pharmaceutical industry. I should show them how they benefit from Big data tools such as Spark to get value out of their data. I should do this talk with an example. Does anyone know what is the best example for pharmacutical industry? I mean what data/ challenges would be better to tackle?

Thanks

Comment: I am by no means an expert in the pharmaceutical industry, but this [article](https://insidebigdata.com/2018/11/23/big-data-critical-pharmaceutical-industry/) might be a good place to get started. There are several examples there that you might be able to dig more into